# Br не дружит с flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Верстал таблицу с помощью flexbox и заметил одну интересную особенность - элемент br ничего не может внутри flexbox.

Пример:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
}
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.new-row, br {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p>Перенос с помощью div'a:</p>
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="new-row"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<p>Перенос с помощью br:</p>
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

В примере у div'а и br одни и те же свойства, но div переносит на новую строку элементы, а br - нет.

Почему?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45087054/1548895

Comment: А зачем вообще использовать <br /> для переноса блочного элемента? Это же противоречит семантике, т.е. это хак сомнительного качества. Для элементов с классом .item лучше поиграть со свойством flex-basis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Реализация элемента `br` в CSS очень хорошо известна как тайна. Различные браузеры поддерживают различные свойства для этого элемента, с разным эффектом (хотя все они поддерживают `display: none`, чтобы удалить `br` из макета). Сам CSS признает эту странность еще в CSS1, выделив [для неё целый подраздел](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#br-elements), и даже сейчас в CSS3 он по-прежнему указан.

Эта особенность flexbox не новая; про неё было известно [с 2014 года](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Jan/0317.html). В основном, в текущих реализациях, `br` не создаёт основной блок, а вместо этого рассматривается как часть непрерывного текста, как описано [в разделе 4 спецификации Flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items), создавая невидимый элемент, который не может быть стилизован (потому что он невидимый). Это похоже на элемент `display: table-cell`, вызывающий создание вокруг себя анонимной таблицы, не смотря на то, что вы можете по-прежнему стилизовать элемент `display: table-cell` - в случае `br` элемент. Свойства стиля, которые вы применяете, не имеют эффекта, а настройки невидимого элемент выставляются по-умолчанию.

В этом случае, поскольку `br` (в основном) пуст, и не имеет никакого свойства во flex'е, это приводит к невидимому элементу flex без каких-либо размеров и "прав", поэтому кажется, что `br` элемент полностью исчез.

Еще в 2014 году CSSWG эта тайна была [решена](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Feb/0055.html) не путем изменения спецификации Flexbox, а просто добавлением специального определения `br` для css-display-3 для учета поведения, которое мы наблюдаем. Но такое определение не существует в [текущей версии](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-css-display-3-20170126) спецификации, а также [FPWD](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-css-display-3-20140220) (который был опубликован после резолюции!), ни HTML-спецификации, ни где-либо еще. Тем не менее, определение выглядит так, как в текущей спецификации css-display-3 (которая не определяет никаких новых свойств, а просто изменяет определение `display`):

```
br {
  content: '\A';
  display: contents;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

...что означает, что элемент `br` [не создаёт основной блок](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-contents), а просто невидимый встроенный блок, содержащий одну новую строку.

Поскольку это определение по-прежнему отсутствует в css-display-3, я бы пока ещё не стал рассматривать его.

<sup>[Ответ участника @BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087054/br-is-not-friendly-with-the-flexbox/45143493#45143493)</sup>

Answer (score 8):

Таки переносит:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
}
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.new-row, br {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
}

br {
  content:'ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, ПЕРЕНЕСИ НА ДРУГУЮ СТРОКУ!';
}
```

```html
<p>Перенос с помощью div'a:</p>
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="new-row"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<p>Перенос с помощью br:</p>
<div class="flexbox">
<div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да Вы, простите, хитрожопый ) Неплохо, не знал про content у br

Comment: Но хотелось бы ещё узнать, почему при одинаковых свойствах не переносит... )

Comment: @Yuri я вот тоже не знал)

Comment: ахаха, как я сразу об этом не подумал!) молодец

Comment: @Yuri интересно то, что высоту для br задать можно, а ширину - нет...

Comment: @Yuri хотя вру, ширину тоже можно задать

Comment: Firefox: переноса нет.

Comment: @Cheg В IE, Edge, Firefox это вообще не работает. Результат вижу только в Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Тег br не имеет своей ширины и высоты, а после применения свойства flex он встал в ряд с остальными. В первом примере вы растягиваете блок на всю ширину, что позволяет занять ей всю строку. С br такой трюк не получится

Comment: Высоту то как раз и имеет.

Comment: @Cheg делая элемент строковым необходим ему необходимо содержимое. Хорошее решение

Comment: @Nikolay Это только в Chrome работает. Супер решение.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov разве контент только в хроме работает?

Comment: @Nikolay А вы запустите его ответ не в хроме.